# How to implement the "pipeline pattern" in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

as far as I understand in ROS the connections between nodes are implicitely given by topic names. So for example node A provides "camera_image", and node B subscribes to "camera_image", and provides "edge_detections". Now, A and B are connected. The names are hard-coded in the nodes source files.

But what if I want to install a node C between A and B, which takes "camera_image", provides "black_and_white_image"? Node B now should no longer subscribe to "camera_image", but to "black_and_white_image".

Of course I don't want to change the source of B. Should I pass the topic name as command line argument?

What is my fundamental misunderstanding here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171861/how-to-implement-the-%22pipeline-pattern%22-in-ros?/) by [foopeter](https://answers.ros.org/users/18676/foopeter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default topic names are coded into the nodes in question, but they can be changed at runtime through [remapping arguments.](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments)

In your example, you would remap the input topic of node B to `black_and_white_image`, like:

```
rosrun pkg_B B_node camera_image:=black_and_white_image
```

Note that the topic type is also hardcoded, and cannot be changed at runtime unless the node explicitly supports it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-05-29**:
Also, you can conveniently remap in launch files: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

**Comment by [foopeter](https://answers.ros.org/users/18676/foopeter/) on 2014-06-02**:
Thank you, this makes it very clear!